# Spotify window size problem

Tags: window, resize, fullscreen, spotify, client

I installed Spotify client on Xubuntu 14.04.

What is pretty annoying is that I am not able to fullscreen the window (even when running as sudo - no errors in terminal generated).

It also doesn't keep the windows size when resized manually (alt + right mouse dragging). To me it looks like Spotify is trying to put its app right under the other opened app (2nd screenshot).

[Before minimize](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RCEyG.jpg)

[After minimize](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pEdcV.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Window resizing problems like this are pretty much solved in the 1.x client (currently in beta for Linux, see the Spotify community forums for a link).

Comment: @OndřejDoležal  http://download.spotify.com/beta/spotify-client_1.0.1.1062_amd64.deb